# Unable to separate the list data even though I have used a ListView.Separated

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm unable to separate my list data using ListView.Separated. All the data is getting displayed without any separator in between them even though I have given a certain width in the separator. Can anyone tell me how I can separate it?

**Code:**

```
 Widget uirow3() {
    return Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
        height: 250,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
                colors: [Colors.blue.shade200, Colors.blue.shade50]),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.1),
                spreadRadius: 5,
                blurRadius: 7,
                offset: Offset(0, 3),
              )
            ]),
        child: ListView.separated(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Container(
              child: uirow3data(weatherInfo, index),
            );
          },
          separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return SizedBox(width: 20);
          },
          itemCount: weatherInfo.weatherListInfo.length,
        ));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code hope its helpful to you.refer `ListView.separated()` [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.separated.html)

> If your `ListView` is **Horizontal**:

```
 Container(
              height: 50.0,
              child: ListView.separated(
                itemCount: 25,
                separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return const IntrinsicHeight(
                    child: VerticalDivider(
                      thickness: 2,
                      width: 20,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  );
                },
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Container(
                    width: 100,
                    child: ListTile(
                      title: Text(
                        'item $index',
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
```

Your result screen using horizontal list : [image: image 1]

> If your `ListView` is **Vertical**:

```
 ListView.separated(
              itemCount: 25,
              separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return const Divider(
                  thickness: 1,
                  color: Colors.black,
                );
              },
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Container(
                  width: 100,
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(
                      'item $index',
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
```

Your result screen using Vertical List-> [image: image 2]

Comment: Got the solution. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome @Poojitha if your problem has been solved by my answer so accept it.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `Divider` instead of `SizedBox` as follows:

```
separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
  return const Divider(
    color: Colors.grey,
    thickness: 1.0,
    height: 1.0,
  );
},
```

Comment: Tried that but didn't work. I got the answer though. Thanks.

Comment: If the solution is one of the ones listed here, please upvote it and make that the accepted answer. If your solution is none of these, please post your solution as an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I just had to wrap the child where I'm calling the data with a card.